# Do deindexed URLs pass link juice?

Tags: 301-redirect, search-engine-indexing, backlinks, link-juice

I am building some backlinks to a page of my website that is high likely to get deindexed (**I have to** build to that specific page) **mainly** because of duplicate content.

Will my page, if deindexed, pass link juice if I permanently redirect (301) it to another page (also within my website)?

Comment: You appear to be asking about redirects.  They pass link juice.  If you deindex a page using the `noindex` tag, that works differently: [Google: Long Term Noindex Will Lead To Nofollow Also](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-long-term-noindex-follow-24990.html)